# how to make a customized variable space in Python

Tags: python

I want to make my own variable workspace like `locals()` or `globals()` and I wonder if I can make a variable search its value from customized variable space.

An example

```py
var_workspace={}

def pre_load(pfcn):
    def wrapper(func):
        def inner_wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
            kw=pfcn()
            if kw !=None:
                kwargs.update(kw)
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        return inner_wrapper
    return wrapper

def init():
    print('inited!')
    # do something here
    return {'w':1}

@pre_load(init)
def system(w=10):
    print('w',w)

>>> system()
inited!
w 1
```

The problem is **I don't want to declare `w=10` as default parameter of system()**, I want to use some variables such as `w` directly in `system()` and to initiate these variables in separate function like `init()`.

Certainly, global variable maybe a solution but there're too many variables in my simulation program and global vars are not easy to manage. So, I want to create a customized variable space, and make initialization of variables in a function like `init()`, and run `system()` separately. How can I implement that?

Comment: you might want to see `class` in python

Comment: What is this for? I imagine that there has to be a simpler way, no?

Comment: Why not use a dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use classes:

```
class System:
    def __init__(self, w):
        self.w = w
        print('invited!')

system = System(10) # invited!
print(system.__dict__) # {'w': 10}
```

See more details about classes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: You don't even need to make `dict_` yourself - `system.__dict__` already exists